# Kernel panic RIP switch_mm_irqs_off first reboot after Ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: boot, 20.04, kernel

I got an old supermicro server and installed fresh Ubuntu 20.04, but the kernel panic during first reboot, tried Ubuntu 16.04 and 22.04, same kernel panic, is this hardware problem, [kernel boot panic video clip](https://youtu.be/YIBhi652VX8), kernel panic at 7 seconds

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I do have hardware problem, after unplug one of the CPU, the server booted fine. ChatGPT helped solving the problem :) see [Will ChatGPT help solving kernel panic problem](https://youtu.be/AYkMNWlVAjg)